# How to use jquery/Jscript to achieve the following?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just wondering with the following,

```
var SelectedPlacementIds = [];
SelectedPlacementIds[0] = 4;
SelectedPlacementIds[1] = 5;

filterValues['SelectedPlacementIds[0]'] = SelectedPlacementIds[0];
filterValues['SelectedPlacementIds[1]'] = SelectedPlacementIds[1];
```

how can I replace that filtervalues code (the above two lines) in a loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for jQuery, you can try this:

```
var SelectedPlacementIds = [4, 5];
$(SelectedPlacementIds).each(function(i,e){
    filterValues['SelectedPlacementIds[' + i + ']'] = e;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you want to do it like this ... but this is the code

```
var thelength = SelectedPlacementIds.length;
for(var i=0; i<thelength; i++) {
   filterValues['SelectedPlacementIds[' + i + ']'] = SelectedPlacementIds[i];
}
```

where `i` is your loop variable

Comment: there is no loop variable... i wanted to know how u would do it in a loop

Comment: So what does your loop look like? Or is it the loop design that you are missing?

Comment: faster than `.each` on a simple array